# RDLC Subreport Parameter NOT Filtering. VS 2015

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, reportviewer

After two weeks of working on a simple report that should have taken one day; Im here looking for help from anyone.
I am creating a local report with version 12 of the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll, I am using VS 2015 VB
I have a report and sub report that show on the web form, but the sub report is not filtering on the Parameter I have set.

I have followed https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160348.aspx and almost every other example I have found on the web. but I cant get the filter to work.

This should be simple, but it is not.  It seems that the filter is not being applied, but I dont see why.

I dont know what code you would like to see, but here is some:

CODE BEHIND:

```
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        AddHandler ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing, AddressOf Me.localReport_SubreportProcessing
    End If

Catch exc As Exception
    Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(Me, exc)
End Try
```

End Sub

'All we’ve done here is, we’re binding the data set to appropriate report data source**.

Private Sub localReport_SubreportProcessing(sender As Object, e As SubreportProcessingEventArgs)

```
e.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("Guardian", "ObjectDataSource2"))
Me.ReportViewer1.DataBind()
```

End Sub

ASPX PAGE

```
    <%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="View.ascx.vb" Inherits="Christoc.Modules.MyEasyDirectoryDirectory.View" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MEZD_DBO %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT organization_admin.OrgID FROM Additional_Guardian INNER JOIN Student ON Additional_Guardian.StudentID = Student.StudentID INNER JOIN organization_admin ON Student.OrgID = organization_admin.OrgID WHERE (organization_admin.Admin_Email = @EMail) OR (Student.G1_Email_Address = @EMail) OR (Additional_Guardian.AG_Email_Address = @EMail)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="EMail" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>


<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" DocumentMapWidth="100%" SizeToReportContent="True">
    <LocalReport ReportPath="C:\inetpub\MyEasyDirectory\DesktopModules\MyEasyDirectoryDirectory\Student.rdlc">
        <DataSources>
            <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="Student" />
             <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource2" Name="Guardian" />
        </DataSources>
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="Christoc.Modules.MyEasyDirectoryDir.DataSet1TableAdapters.StudentTableAdapter">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="ORGID" Type="Int64" />

</SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>





<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="Christoc.Modules.MyEasyDirectoryDirectory.GuardianDataSetTableAdapters.Additional_GuardianTableAdapter">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Here is the report, that is incorrect.
The Report should filter based on the student ID.  If you look at the picture, the Parameter StudID is in the upper right (This is what is being passed as a parameter to the sub report).
The second most right Number is the data in the DB that should be filtered.

As you can see, the first record should only show 2 items, the second and third records should have no items.

[image: This is a picture of the report]

Answer (score 0):

I guess this was a bug in VS 2015.  I blew away the entire project, and re-created it.  Same code.  But this time it compiled.  "Un-documented Feature" I guess.